# Use a flashvar that contains quotes and other marks?

Tags: actionscript-3, flashvars

Is there something I can do to make it so that a flashvar can contain any sort of punctuation and not break the html code? Like some sort of encompassing brackets or something? Right now if I try to include some long strings that have quote marks or other characters that could have some sort of meaning in the code, then it tends to interpret it as code rather than a string. Anything I can do?

Comment: Have you tried urlencoding the flashVars?

Answer (score 1):

I have never tried doing something like this, but a quick search on Google gave me this link:
http://www.mail-archive.com/swfobject@googlegroups.com/msg02600.html

Maybe you should give a go to the encodeURIComponent() method in JS.

More about the method:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp

Rob

Comment: that's interesting, but I'm not sure I can/know how to insert that into flashvars html side. I guess I'll just stick with loading an external rss xml, I just wish I could make it be available at the start up of flash vs having to load flash, then load the xml. When having to hit the database for more info, it always takes a while and there's "Loading" or blank content on the screen for long than I'd like.

Comment: i've tried using the script to insert it into a flashvar, but i just get a blank. I must be doing it wrong.

Comment: I think it is much better to load the XML then make your html unnecessarily ugly ;)

Comment: i dislike how long it takes for the server to generate the XML. I'm looking into a way to get wordpress to generate an xml file that is only updated on the posting of new content, not every time someone calls the file.